# How can session_start cause my page to get stuck

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Ive seen a few people with the same problem, and I created a VERY simple test file. So I'm SURE its because of `session_start`. I've had this wired problem for days now and narrowed things down to this....

MY TEST FILE :)
I basically start my page with `<? @session_start(); ?>` (nothing before the first `<?` not even a space) Then create `$myyear = date("Y");` And if `$myyear > 2000` I refresh the page after 2 seconds (with a meta refresh)

So it keeps refreshing, refreshen refreshing....
but after about a minute it gets stuck.

if i remove session_start or `@session_start` it suddenly works forever.
So it can only be session_start causing the problem -> even through i don't even create a real session.

Any idea how this can be fixed? or what i should be looking for?

Comment: Does the error log show anything?

Comment: If not, try removing the `@` and check the log again. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: the same code jcsanyi posted.
error log shows nothing int he last 3 hours, reproduced the problem 5 times. Also tried without the @

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I've come up with the following code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $myyear = date('Y');
    if ($myyear > 2000) {
        echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">');
    }
?>
Page Contents (<?php echo(time()) ?>)
```

This works as expected for me.
If it works for you as well, please figure out what's different between your code and this.

Comment: 1) error logs shows nothing in the last 3 hours - i reproduced the problem 5 times. UPS idling full message now....

Comment: 1) error logs shows nothing in the last 3 hours - i reproduced the problem 5 times.
2) I'm not on a shared hosting plan and I'm trying on 2 different servers from the same company, but one located in LA and the other one in Virginia. paying 50$ per month for VPS plans
3) yes jcsany - that's exactly the code.... but i made it even simpler now... so it's just like your code but without the "page conents" at the end. It refreshes for a few minutes and then gets stuck like if Im loading a huge page. It doesn't get slower gradually, it just gets stuck at once.

Comment: Should i contact the hosting provider?
The ONLY change i made to php.ini was increasing the cockie and session lifetime to 12 hours. But that was yesterday it also happened before...

Comment: ACTUALLY.. sometimes it looks like it gets stuck -> loading for 10 seconds and then it runs again, and sometimes it really gets stuck... loading forever